# RabbitMQ in Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, rabbitmq

I'd would like to use RabbitMQ .I find nugget .NET but i get error :

You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

How Can I implement connection with RabbitMQ . Manual copy source ?

Comment: I assume you are using the RabbitMQ.Client 3.5.6 package?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the RabbitMQ nuget package needs the full .NET Framework. Since PCLs and Xamarin Android projects don't provide the full framework, it won't work. One option is to take the source code and build it in a PCL like you suggested (eg see https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/49858/using-rabbitmq-amqp-with-xamarin-forms). Depending on what you want to do, I think using the [HTTP API](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) might be worth considering too.

Answer (score 1):

Rabbit MQ is now also built as a .net standard 1.5 libraries. https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client

You should be able to pull it into the latest Xamarin without any problems (taking into account that your xamarin build is set up to support version .net standard 1.5 or version 2.0).
Xamarin forms added support for standard libraries from version 2.3.5-pre
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/building-xamarin-forms-apps-net-standard/

UWP is easily supported with .net standard 2.0 and is compatible with the 1.5 libraries.